# create real mode elf file and link it to my kernel

Tags: kernel, interrupt, elf, bios, vga

I'm trying to turn on graphic mode in VGA (in a our course kernel - JOS).
I found that to do so I need to call interrupt 10h from real mode (8086). 
However, getting to real mode after you got to protected mode is a problem so I'm trying to use V86 mode.
I found that in order to use V86 mode I need to run it as a task, so now I'm working on adding support for V86 processes.
My kernel is limited and does not contain a proper file system, so in order to load the real mode code I'm trying to compile and link it all together (the kernel and the v86 task).

So does anyone knows how to create an Elf for real mode?
Also, if anyone can give me tips on how to link it together with the kernel it would be great!

Thanks,
Shai.

Answer (score 1):

This will have to be a quick answer but:

I don't know how/if you can link together the real mode and protected mode code directly. However, there are two things you might try:

1. You could compile your real mode code down to a flat binary (stripping out all of the metadata) and package it in with your kernel (maybe by appending it to the end of the kernel image or some other way). You would then need to find it at runtime, load it in to memory, and then jmp/call in to it. Since I don't know anything about how your kernel is packaged or run though, so this may be quite difficult.
2. Directly add the machine code to an assembly file that you link with your kernel. I don't have a real example but it might look something like this:

   ```
   EnterRealMode:
       db    0b8h, 00h, 00h            ; mov ax, 00h
       db    0fe, 0ebh                 ; jmp $
       etc.
   ```

Also, you probably want to actually thunk down to real mode instead of using virtual 8086 mode. The memory mapping and interrupts for the BIOS call will probably be all wonky if you don't. [Advice on thunking down to real mode.](https://www.google.com/search?q=thunking%20to%20real%20mode&oq=thunking%20to%20real%20mode)